# Make flowlayoutPanel in c# winforms touch scrollable to the right and left

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I'm trying to make my flowlayoutPanel in winform .NET framework touch scrollable on a touchscreen to the right and left. I have found a Youtube tutorial that shows how to achieve touch scrollability but its only up and down.

This is what I tried but it only works for up and down touch scroll, how do I make it so it touch scrolls to right and left instead of up and down?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VendingMachineProject
{
    public class TouchScroll
    {
        private Point mouseDownPoint;
        private FlowLayoutPanel parentPanel;
    

    public TouchScroll(FlowLayoutPanel panel)
    {
        parentPanel = panel;
        AssignEvent(panel);
    }

    private void AssignEvent(Control control)
    {
        control.MouseDown += MouseDown;
        control.MouseMove += MouseMove;
        foreach(Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            AssignEvent(child);
        }
    }

    private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
            return;

        Point pointDifference = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + mouseDownPoint.X, Cursor.Position.Y - mouseDownPoint.x);

        if ((mouseDownPoint.X == Cursor.Position.X) && (mouseDownPoint.Y == Cursor.Position.Y))
            return;

        Point currAutoS = parentPanel.AutoScrollPosition;
        parentPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Math.Abs(currAutoS.X) - pointDifference.X, Math.Abs(currAutoS.Y) - pointDifference.Y);
        mouseDownPoint = Cursor.Position;

    }

    private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            this.mouseDownPoint = Cursor.Position;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: did you try reversing the X and Y so it does the opposite of up and down which is left and right?

Comment: [Windows Touch Gestures Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/windows-touch-gestures-overview) -- [Windows Touch Gestures in C# Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/windows-touch-gestures-in-c--sample--mtgesturescs-) -- If you want to a simplified method (without handling gestures), I suggest implementing `IMessageFilter` in a custom FlowLayoutPanel and intercept all messages before they're sent to the child Controls, so you can also remove all those event handlers

Comment: Scrolling only works if there is something outside the view. Is you control larger than the width of the view? Do you have a horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @jdweng yes the horisontal scrollbars are visible because something is outside the flowlayoutpanel but the problem is i can only scroll it by dragging the scrollbars, But i want it to be scrollable by just dragging it like touch screens do

Comment: Where is Cursor defined?  Is it in the designer?  You haver two cursors (horizontal and vertical) but only one variable. You need a CursorUpDown and CursorLeftRight variable.  Then duplicate code for each Cursor.

Comment: @jdweng could you edit the code and post it?